# How to set value of prop in a useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

so I'm trying to pass a dynamically generated URL to `Image`'s `source` prop and, due to React Native limitations, I cannot simply pass a variable as the value of that prop because it won't update to load the image after the variable is set.

So I'm trying to follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71263771/8561357) to trigger a change to the `source` prop.

How can I set the value of a prop in useEffect?

Edit: this is what I'm trying, but still not successfully seeing the image

```
  const [photoUrl, setPhotoUrl] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getSetImg() {
      let img = await getImage(job.afterPhoto.uri);
      setPhotoUrl(img);
    }
    if (job) {
      getSetImg;
    }
  }, [job]);
```

```
              <Image
                source={{ uri: photoUrl }}
                style={styles.headerImage}
              />
```

Comment: If you were to set the prop into a useState() then update the state it will trigger a rerender. You can use the useEffect(()=>{setState(url)} , [url]) might do the trick

Comment: @ColinHale that is what I'm doing,  but not seeing the image. `getImage` is indeed returning a string URL

Comment: Can you also add your code where you are also rendering the image. Adding the entire component or making a replica on codesandbox would also be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The problem may not be from setting the values with useState/setState.

I have **2 suggestions** you can try.

## 1. Check if Image style is set explicitly

##### *Q) Does the image show when you hardcode the URL directly (without using setState)?*

**You can try using the Google logo image for uri:  `https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png`**

- NO (Image don't show): Try the below (style)
- YES (Hardcoded image is shown ok): Try #2 (ATS)

From [RN Docs on Image](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image):

> Note that for network and data images, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image!

If your `styles.headerImage` does not have `height` and `width` explicitly defined, the `<Image/>` component may not show. You can easily check if your `<Image/>` component is visible by setting the `backgroundColor='red'` while developing.

## 2. Check [App Transport Security (ATS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) settings

##### *Q) Are you using iOS? Is the uri source in https or http?*

If you are fetching image in http, check the ATS settings.

Also from [RN Docs on ATS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/publishing-to-app-store#1-enable-app-transport-security):

> App Transport Security is a security feature introduced in iOS 9 that rejects all HTTP requests that are not sent over HTTPS.

[Suggested fix from another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363339/react-native-app-transport-security-has-blocked) is to add `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in the `info.plist`.

Comment: Thanks @Ziwon, the hardcoded url works (thought I tested that before but guess not). The url is https so it probably comes down to arbitrary loads. I actually got the state value -> prop approach to work, just forgot to call the function in my useEffect like `getSetImg()`